# React props not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent class component that has a function in `componentWillMount` that loops through a list of strings and creates an element for each one and finally `setState` on `this.state.map`. Each child element receives a prop which is a state in parent called `this.state[element]`.

The reason I put these elements into `this.state.map` was because I can change things in (some) upper components without having to re-render the array each time (which is painfully slow) and I didn't want to use `shouldComponentUpdate`. Plus in the future I can just quickly change elements by toggling different map states.

The problem is, when the parent `this.state[element]` (that's passed to child as props in the initial `componentWillMount`) changes, it doesn't update the props for the child. Parent state does change though.

Is this a legit way to do this?
I'm sorry I didn't provide code sample. It's just such a mess at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Only ReactDOM.render (and serverside rendering etc.), setState, or forceUpdate, will cause your children to re-render. If you are just mutating the state object, React is unaware of this, and will not re-render. Anyways, mutating the state not through setState is not valid, and you should try to keep your state as immutable as possible. In order for you to see the changes in your children, you need to use `setState` to update `this.state[element]`.

From the React docs:

> Notes:
>   NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

Comment: I've been using react-addons-update to update state then used setState.